# No visual-line-mode in emacs! How to set line wrap?

Tags: osx, wrapping

I am using Emacs on mac osx 10.7*. I have the LongLines mode where long sentences are truncated on screen with `$` symbol. `M-x visual-line-mode` does not exist in my Emacs. That is when I type `M-x` and then `visual` and `TAB` it says no such command, nothing with `visual`. How to set line wrap in this situation?

Comment: What does `M-x emacs-version RET` report?

Comment: According to `describe-symbol`, _visual-line-mode is an interactive compiled Lisp function in ‘simple.el’_. In my system (emacs version 25.3 installed through homebrew), you can find simple.el with the following command `find /usr/local/Cellar/emacs/25.3/ | grep simple.el `

Comment: Visual line mode has been part of Emacs since 23.1, released in 2009, so you've either got a very old version of Emacs, or something very strange has happened in your config. https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/78479a3984047a8153b43571e6b5ebfb674223a4/etc/NEWS.23#L1299

Comment: If you want a current self-contained Emacs version that is pre-built, have a look at:  https://emacsformacosx.com/  It has nothing extra -- it is just a vanilla build for OSX.

Comment: My emacs version is : GNU Emacs 22.1.1 (mac-apple-darwin) of 2012-08-24. I am using osX lion and the emacs is the default one. For Updating it I might have to install newer verison and change links (https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/229669/update-emacs-that-comes-with-os-x). Should I update or is there a similar command for line wrap in this old version. Thanks guys !

Answer (score 3):

The problem was the version. I installed emacs version - 25.3 from port. Now it works. emacs-25.3 gets installed in /opt/local/bin and one can rename it so that emacs command from terminal opens it. And emacs in /usr/bin can be renamed to emacs-22 so that it can still be accessed and there is no conflict.